# Another called script not going into background even given &

Tags: shell, gzip, subshell

I have 2 scripts.

I'm calling my `script2` as `sh scriptpath/script2.sh &` inside `script1`
which compresses files using a combination of `find`, `xargs` and `gzip` commands on 16 files at a time. It is basically a file watcher script integrated to run the process below after checking if a file is present. (Not cron)

Reference: https://it.toolbox.com/question/file-watcher-script-070510

```
find ${Filepath}/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${Pattern}" -print0 | xargs -0 -t -n 1 -P 16 gzip > /dev/null
```

After calling my script 2, it's hanging at the command above.

Script1 session is getting closed and script2's shell is opening up with above command status. I need the gzip command of the second script to be run in the background and not the foreground.

Script1 - Generates few files. Exports variables to be used in script2

And then calls script2 as `sh script2 needed parameters &` (ampersand to push script2 to go into background) and `script1` completes, but after script 2 finds one touch file. It begins its execution. But the prompt of `script2` where `gzip` is executing after it finds touch file is coming to foreground.

Script2
Gunzips files created before calling script 2

```
fileflag=0
timer1=0
check_interval=300 # check every 5 minutes
(( check_interval_minutes=${check_interval}/60 ))
while [ ${timer1} -lt 180 ]
do
if [ -f /path/to/my/file ]
then
find ${Filepath}/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${Pattern}" -print0 | xargs -0 -t -n 1 -P 16 gzip > /dev/null
else
sleep ${check_interval}
fi
(( timer1=${timer1} ${check_interval_minutes} ))
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your scripts. I am afraid it is impossible to debug your code if you cannot share it. If possible, try to make a simplified example that still reproduces the problem: remove anything not relevant and show us a minimal example of your two scripts that we can use to test our solutions.

Comment: Done..please check and try to answer

Comment: Maybe not relevant to the problem but `timer1=${timer1} ${check_interval_minutes}` is wrong. I guess a `+` is missing there.

Comment: What happens if you just press enter?

Comment: Oh this is reference code, i have added + in my code already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xargs -t` writes to `stderr`. Your `> /dev/null` doesn't affect `stderr`. So you are writing to the terminal from a background process which usually is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Hauke, it worked !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the find/gzip process to happen in the background you can run that entire block in the background by using something like:

```
( find ${Filepath}/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${Pattern}" -print0 | xargs -0 -t -n 1 -P 16 gzip > /dev/null ) &
```

However, depending on how long it takes for all those gzip processes to finish that might be unwise, if it takes longer than the interval between when your script runs you may end up with more than one process attempting to compress the same file.

You would probably be better off using something like `inotifywatch` to watch the directory for files to appear and compress them.

Comment: my gzip happens in seconds, but command still hangs. Standalone script 2 runs fine but while calling from script 1 to 2 gzip command command is coming to foreground even after its successful execution and just staying in there

Comment: There is no need for the brackets around the command.

Comment: Your answer does not address the `xargs -t` problem in the background.